# VBA formulas_Excel_Formulas

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please advise me on how the actual VBA formulas used to generate a pie chart?

I would like 3 reports:

1. To show me Tasks completed, tasks not yet started and tasks in progress
2. Project days passed and project days left
3. Behind schedule tasks - started , behind schedule tasks - not yet started  and scheduled tasks

All I can see is `=SERIES(,Hidden!$M$89:$M$91,Hidden!$N$89:$N$91,1)`.

I would have uploaded a sample but I don't know how.

Your support is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA to make the pie chart, and you'll find it much easier to use the built-in PivotTable and PivotChart features to do so.

Please take a look at this [Microsoft site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-pivottable-and-pivotchart-reports-HP010177384.aspx) for an overview and examples. And try a web search of "Excel pie chart pivot table" if you'd like to research it further.